# Is it Possible to Bind Apache Airflow's Webserver to a Unix Socket?

Tags: nginx, airflow

I'm attempting to set up Apache Airflow with nginx as my proxy. Generally, when I create my own Flask apps, I'll tell gunicorn to `--bind unix:/path/to/socket.sock` and avoid much pain when configuring nginx. I have, so far, found nothing indicating that this is going to work with Airflow, but I could just be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I don't have a solution for binding it into a socket but the airflow's documentation explain how to set up nginx to an airflow serving port 8080
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.12/howto/run-behind-proxy.html

Comment: I had seen that bit as well. Apples and truffles, unfortunately.